# Authentication failed with twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to display tweets of a user, the problem is I got the following error message:

> 06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:201)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1941)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getRetweets(TwitterImpl.java:209)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.afficherTweets(MainActivity.java:286)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:417)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
>   06-28 11:40:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(3191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And this is my code:

```
I changed them but in vain, this is my hole code:

package com.androidhive.twitterconnect;
import java.util.List;

import com.androidhive.twitterconnect.R;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
// Constants
/**
 * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
 * consumer key and secret
 * */
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "****************************";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "***********************************************";

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = " 281012441-vTUstoGd5NpWjoviMDS87JxyS4mjj713CfPNCsh2";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = " 4rfd76K1ZUQ0eb3Zss2q6huAZra4TmWnrtj3dPKODectP";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

// Login button
Button btnLoginTwitter;
// Update status button
Button btnUpdateStatus;
// Logout button
Button btnLogoutTwitter;
Button btnDisplayTwitter;

// EditText for update
EditText txtUpdate;
// lbl update
TextView lblUpdate;
TextView lblUserName;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

// Internet Connection detector
private ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    btnDisplayTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnDisplayTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements
    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);

    /**
     * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
     * */
    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
     * function
     * */
    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            // Check for blank text
            if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                // update status
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
            } else {
                // EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event for logout from twitter
     * */
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    /** This if conditions is tested once is
     * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
     * Verifier
     * */
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Show Update Twitter
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Getting user details from twitter
                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Function to login twitter
 * */
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


////////////////////////////////

public void displayTweets() throws TwitterException{

    /*
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);*/

     //Access Token
    String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    // Access Token Secret
    String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
    System.out.println("==> "+userID);

    try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        //List<Status   > statuses = twitter.getRetweets(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(userID);
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get retweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

///////////////////////////////

/**
 * Function to update status
 * */
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}


/**
 * Function to logout from twitter
 * It will just clear the application shared preferences
 * */
private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();

    // After this take the appropriate action
    // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
    // You might not needed this code
    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUserName.setText("");
    lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
 * fetched from Shared Preferences
 * */
private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v == btnDisplayTwitter){
        try {
            afficherTweets();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication credentials are missing.
```

You're missing credentials somewhere.

From your code, I'd say these :

```
**
 * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
 * consumer key and secret
 * */
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "****************************";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "***********************************************";
```

Comment: I put them from the twitter developer page. how come they are missing? In my case I put * instead of the real numbers.